# How to run a function after div has lost focus?

Tags: jquery, events, blur, focusout

I have several `divs` that each contain a `form`. Each of the forms has two `input text` `fields`.
I am trying to `trigger` a `function` after `div looses focus` (meaning, not after one of the input text fields looses focus, but after totally new form in new div gains focus).

```
<div class='userInput' id='userInputID'>
   <div class='col1'>
    <form id='form1' method='post' action='BuyOrder.php'>
      <input type='text' name='r1' id='r1' value=''><br />
      <input type='text' name='b1' id='b1' value=''><br />
      <button id='button1' class='sendButton'>send</button>
    </form>
   </div>          
   <div class='colX'>
     <form id='formX' method='post' action='BuyOrder.php'>
      <input type='text' name='rX' id='rX' value=''><br />
      <input type='text' name='bX' id='bX' value=''><br />
      <button id='buttonX' class='sendButton'>send</button>
     </form>
   </div>    
   <div class='col2'>
     <form id='form2' method='post' action='BuyOrder.php'>
       <input type='text' name='r2' id='r2' value=''><br />
       <input type='text' name='b2' id='b2' value=''><br />
       <button id='button2' class='sendButton'>send</button>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is jquery code:

```
$('#userInputID').children().blur(function(){        
//some code   

})//end blur
```

Basically, I want the function to run when any of the divs with the class col1, colx or col2 looses focus. 
The jquery code above never even fires. Focusout doesn't work because that fires after each input text fields loose focus, even if the same div still has focus.

Comment: what you trying to achieve here? if u tell us that we'd be able to tell you another way to do this. Because this doesnt seem to be a good solution for anything.

Comment: I need to hide validation warning if user goes to different form inside different div

Comment: why is that one not workin? the selection is done properly. Blur should work on divs, too, right?

Answer (score 0):

### How to fire a function after div has lost focus (blur)

Based on tests and on these pages  [1](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html), [2](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) it seems that blur does not bubble. But you can use a workaround. This [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvA8W/3/) shows that it works according to my understanding of your question:

- for each div that is a child of the div `id='userInputID'`
- create an event listener that fires after the div has lost focus (blur)

If you use the [jQuery function `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can capture focus and blur events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#userInputID" ).on( "blur", "div.onBlurTest", function() {        
        $( this ).toggleClass( "hasFocus" );
        $( this ).addClass( "hasLostFocus" );      
        $( this ).children("h2").text("Using on instead of blur");        
    }); 
});
```

And the html

```
<div class="userInput" id="userInputID">              
  <div class="col2 onBlurTest">
    <h2>Using on instead of blur</h2>
    <form id="form2" method="post" action="BuyOrder.php">
      <input type="text" name="r2" id="r2" value="" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="b2" id="b2" value="" />
      <br />
      <button id="button2" class="sendButton">send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Fully working demo at fiddle with update dec 2013

As Chris Rockwell pointed out [my former fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvA8W/3/) does not work if the tab key is used. I created **[a fork that works with the tab key as well](http://jsfiddle.net/BEccX/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  $( "#userInputID" ).on( "focus", "div.onBlurTest", function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "hasFocus" );
        $( this ).removeClass( "hasLostFocus" );                 
  });

  $( "#userInputID" ).on( "blur", "div.onBlurTest", function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "hasFocus" );
        $( this ).removeClass( "hasLostFocus" );      
  });    
});
```

And simplified HTML

```
<div class="userInput" id="userInputID">              
      <div class="col2 onBlurTest">        
        <form id="form2" method="post" action="BuyOrder.php">
          <input type="text" name="r2" id="r2" value="" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 onBlurTest">     
        <form id="form2" method="post" action="BuyOrder.php">
            <input type="text" name="b2" id="b2" value="" />
        </form>
      </div>        
    </div>
```

Please let me know if you have further questions.

#### Some quotes

From the [jQuery Api on blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

> The `blur` event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore, scripts that rely on event delegation with the `blur` event will not work consistently across browsers. As of version `1.4.2`, however, jQuery works around this limitation by mapping `blur` to the `focusout` event in its event delegation methods, `.live()` and `.delegate()`.

Comment: so, what your basically saying it that it's not doable this way

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think your fiddle is working in the way expected.  In Chrome, when I tab into the form, it doesn't toggle the class; it appears to be attached to each individual form element, not the entire form.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell i revisited my answer and you are correct. If using tab to move through the form-fields the class is not set as desired. I updated my fiddle and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.blur()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) would lead you to believe that you can use it this way; however, I believe you must explicitly trigger the blur on an element that is not a valid form element (e.g. input, select, etc.);

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7VYQ/

Based on your comment regarding validation, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7aLb/3/) shows you how to determine the currently focused form, and make adjustments to the other forms.