# First option of select should not be selected automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used bootstrap select js. Following is the code used for select

```
<select data-required="true" name="option" class="selectpicker" multiple >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Pick the once that apply to u</option>
    <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
    <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
    <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```

If I don't add `selected` in first option then validation doesn't take place and but if I do then first option get automatically selected.

Please give me some solution that both should work -

1. Validation
2. First option should not get automatically selected

this is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guggu2007/Luqh5ujw/1/)

Comment: and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Lal that is what i don't know. May be little customization of bootstrap select is needed

Comment: Sorry...didnt get you...what is that you actually need?

Comment: @Lal Problem is that even if i don't select the first option it gets selected automatically

Comment: Remove `selected` from your first option..

Comment: then form validation doesn't take place

Comment: What are you using for form validation?

Comment: @Roger LipscombeI think step form js is validating the fields

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the selected attribute from your first option. Something like:

```html
<select data-required="true" name="option" class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option value="" disabled>Pick the items that apply to u</option>
  <option value="1">Shipping / post</option>
  <option value="2">Customers can collect</option>
  <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```

You should then consider adding the validation on 'lost focus' or during form submit.

**note**

You 'final validation' should be done server side, as client side validation can be 'hacked' or mislead. This is why important validation should be done on the server/

Comment: Can you give me some reference for the lost focus validation

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029132/how-to-run-a-function-after-div-has-lost-focus